# How to execute with Jooq arbitrary number of selects joined with UNION

Tags: java, sql, union, jooq

I want to execute UNION of `List<Select>` like

```
SELECT #1
UNION
SELECT #2
UNION
...
```

How can I do it with Jooq?

UPDATE:
In my method I check a set of parameters and if their are not nul add subquery to the list. I need functionality like strings joiner.

So I solved my task by downgrading to raw sql and using `Joiner(" UNION ").join(List<String>subqueries)`

Comment: did you already see the documentation about `union`? https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.9/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/select-statement/union-clause/

Comment: Yes, I did. I need something like `create.union(listOfSelects)` but can't fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the following could be applied to call `union` on several `Select`s.

```
<T extends Record> Result<T> fetchUnion(List<Select<T>> selects) {
    return selects.stream()
                  .reduce(Select::union)
                  .map(Select::fetch)
                  .orElseThrow(() -> /* your exception? */);
}
```

Note that I did not yet test it and you may need to alter it a bit to get it working. Alternatively:

```
<T extends Record> Result<T> fetchUnion(Select ... selects) {
   return Stream.of(selects)
                .reduce(Select::union)
                .map(Select::fetch)
                .orElse ... ;
}
```

A possible call could then be:

```
Result result = fetchUnion(select(T1.A, T1.B).from(T1), 
                           select(T2.A, T2.B).from(T2), 
                           select(T3.A, T3.B).from(T3));
```

The static import mentioned by Lukas is also required here:

```
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;
```

Comment: I like you solution, but it still not as convenient as `create.union(listOfSelects)` as it requires to get first element of the list as separated

Comment: added a untested `listOfSelects`-reduction-variant

Comment: well, Select::union doesn't conform to `reduce(BinaryOperator<T> accumulator)` of the `Stream<T>`

Comment: I adapted the answer a bit... it compiles here but I can not test it against a DB yet...

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
using(configuration)
   .select(T1.A, T1.B)
   .from(T1)
   .union(
    select(T2.A, T2.B)
   .from(T2))
   .union(
    select(T3.A, T3.B)
   .from(T3))
   .fetch();
```

The above answer is assuming the following import:

```
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;
```

Comment: But I have a dynamic collection. I have N tables and want to create a method to do request from 1 to N of them depending on method parameters. It's convenient for me to use builder and join subqueries with UNION at the end. So I went the "string way": collected raw sql to a list and joined them as with Joiner(" UNION ").

Comment: I see. Unfortunately, there currently isn't any API support for something like `union(Select...)` because the resulting type has no representation in the jOOQ `QueryPart` hierarchy: a pre-union-order-by-step.